# Donaldson's proof of Narasimhan Seshadri theorem

Tags: complex-geometry

I would like to know what in the Donaldson's proof make it work only for Riemann surfaces.

Comment: What non-Riemann surfaces (or Riemann non-surfaces) did you have in mind?

Comment: I guess the meaning of question was "why it works in 2d but not for higher dimensional manifolds ?". In that formulation question is reasonable and I tried to explain the reasons in my answer below. So I would suggest to reformulate the question rather than close it.

Comment: Alexander: the state of being closed is *precisely* for that.

Comment: Since nick "cedric" seems to be new on MO, I would suggest at least give some clear suggestions to him what should be done. Otherwise it does not seems to be friendly attitude to new-comers. Although I, of course, agree that the formulation of the question is beyond reasonable level of clearness and standards of asking questions on any public site - MO in particular.

Comment: @Cedric I would suggest to clarify the question. Do you really interested in that 1) "why it works in 2d but not for higher dimensional manifolds ?" 2) It would be polite if you give at least some brief comments on what is Narasimhan-Seshadri theorem is about - this is natural requirement of at least trying to make question self-contained written in MO's "FAQ".

Comment: @Cedric "closed" - does not mean "deleted" - it can be opened again. I hope this will happen if you clarify yours question.

Comment: Have you looked at these other papers of Donaldson?
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0765366
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0885784

Comment: Alexander Chervov: Even though I voted to close the question, I applaud your attitude in the above comments.  I would happily vote to reopen the question if it were edited to make it clear just what the question is.  I tend to be pretty charitable on this issue, but this question fails to meet even my permissive standards.

Answer (score 4):

Briefly speaking the answer is **because moment map for the action of gauge group is CURVATURE in 2-d and (hence moment level = 0 you get FLAT connections)** and in higher - dimensions the appropriately understood moment map will have form curvature*omega^n ,
where omega is the kaehler form and so what you get is related to ant-self dual connections in 4d and to something well-known (but I do not remember) in higher dimensions.

---

Some more details.

Actually from some point of view you are not quite right. 
Actually in moral sense it works in higher dimensions - but what you get is not flat connections but (anti) - self-dual connections and what you get is Ulenbeck-Yau (??) theorem 
that moduli of holomorphic bundles is the same as moduli and moduli space of (anti)-self-dual connections.

May be it worth to understand the moral of the proofs which is quite simple and then it clarifies the conclusions.

The key idea for understanding - is the following finite-dimensional fact:
Let G - be complex semi-simple group, U - its compact subgroup, M - kaehler manifold.

Then M/G = M//U  where "//" is symplectic reduction.

This is a quite non-trivial fact.

All theorems above are applications of the above principle in infinite-dimensional setup.

When you consider M - moduli space of all smooth connections on some manifold N.
G - is "gauge group" - group of smooth automorpisms of vector bundle.
U - is subgroup of some orthogonal automorphims ( you need to choose metric on your bundle).

Since evrything is infinite-dimensional you cannot apply theorem above directly, but you
as a guidence principle it works and people were able to overcome infinit-dim. difficulties and get the desired results.

PS

I am not sure I presented details correctly, but idea I am sure is correct.

Most of this I heard from Misha Verbitsky - may be if You alert him about this question
he will answer you here (as you can see now he is not often on MO).